# The UV Unwrapping jumbled everything into a mess!

Tags: uv

I can't explain this very well as I'm a bit of a newbie at 3D Modeling and UV Mapping just happens to be my least favorite part. however I DO have photos. Basically, whenever I try to "unwrap" everything, Blender kinda just....unwraps nearly ever single face. I'm really confused what do I do here?

[image]

Comment: Your outliner shows lots of separate meshes, how much more are there? Looks like it's just unwrapped mesh by mesh.

Comment: Okay so, I've been playing around with it (thank you everyone for your answers) and I did a couple of things, first I unwrapped it without using the Smart UV thing. It fixed scattering everything about but it still is pretty....uh....difficult to understand? So I joined a lot of things together to see if that would help but it didn't. I do not have the ability to insert a photo here though it seems :(

Answer (score 2):

As @taiyo says, there are a lot of objects which you have all selected together. If you select a single object and press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap it, the UV space will be (more or less optimized) filled with the faces of this object (simply spoken, of course this depends on the chosen options and if there are seams etc.).

If you select multiple objects, Blender will place them so that they will all fit into the UV space without overlapping - and in order to achieve that, they have to be smaller of course, the more objects, the smaller. Usually overlapping does not matter on separate objects, but since you unwrapped them together, Blender assumes you want them to share one UV space (for example, to have a single image texture for all objects). And maybe you want to unwrap them together, then it depends on which settings you use, see 3. and 4. further down.

1. Unwrapping a single object:

   [image: single unwrap]
2. Unwrapping multiple objects together:

   [image: multiple unwraps]
3. Using *Unwrapping* method *Smart UV Project* with the default settings, *Angle Limit* 66° (angle above which mesh islands are separated) and *Island Margin* 0.000:

   [image: smart uv project default]
4. Now the same method, but changed values, *Angle Limit* 5° and *Island Margin* 0.100, this way the mesh will be separated in much more islands with a larger margin than before:

   [image: smart uv project new settings]

Comment: It also looks as if the Margin setting may have been increase from the default .001 setting on the Unwrap properties and possibly that every edge on all the objects have been marked as a Seam.  We'd need to see the Blend file to be able to see exactly what's going in.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: @JohnEason Yeah, you are probably right about the margin. However, the screenshot does not show any seams, my guess is the option _Smart UV Project_ was used for unwrapping, with a low _Angle Limit_ and an increased _Island Margin_. Maybe I should edit this into my answer, although it is just an assumption.

Comment: It's always a bit difficult to tell when the whole model is selected.  That's why I asked for the Blend file! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason Don't know about your Blender, but mine shows the seams even if all models are selected ;) And the Blend file will not show you which Unwrapping method was used and what the settings were. It will also not tell you if unwrapping all models together is intended here or just done by accident / lack of experience. This is something only the OP knows and can tell us, and that's why I explained what could have lead to the result to give the OP an idea. And maybe you should ask for the file below the question, it might be the OP does not realize this because it is a comment on my answer.

Comment: Oh! I did actually do that! I was following a tutorial on creating a sims 3 object, and the tutorial had me make a "Smart UV" Unwrap, it also said to make my Island Margin 3-4 pixels, but the tutorial didn't really state how to do that so I though that meant changing the default margin to ".040". The tutorial was using a very old version of Blender (about 2010)